# Are edits to convert code to newer language versions appropriate?

Tags: discussion, edits

I got the following suggested edit on an answer I posted over 3 years ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17325311

All it does is add an EcmaScript 6 rewrite of the code in my answer. I rejected it as "No improvement whatsoever". As I continued in the review queue, I noticed other answers that were just converting traditional JS code to ES6, or adding Python 3 code to Python 2 answers, etc.

My first inclination in all these cases is that it should be up to the original answerer to decide whether he wants to use the newer syntax. These edits should perhaps just be comments suggesting updating the code. What do others think?

Comment: Looks like he just did that there to get past the minimum character limit for suggested edits. He wanted to change the greater-than sign to a minus sign, but the system wouldn't let him make that edit, so he tried to add more value by including an updated code sample. It is your answer, so it's ultimately your prerogative to reject that you want, but the consideration should not be "is it allowed", but rather "does it make the answer better for future viewers?"

Comment: Personally, if someone knows what they're doing (and that's a big "if", I realize, but bear with me), I would *much* rather them just go ahead and make/suggest the edit. It saves me a lot of time and effort compared to them leaving a comment requesting me to update the answer.

Comment: Is there a way for me to change my mind about the rejection? Or would you like to approve it?

Comment: Being a moderator, I can override your rejection and approve it if you want. I'm not trying to pressure you into approving it, though.

Comment: Not pressured. The concensus seems to be that these types of edits are reasonable as long as they don't remove the original answer, just add to it.

Comment: I might even have overreacted originally by not noticing that he left the original JS code.

Comment: Yeah, that way of thinking makes sense to me. As long as they're not trying to add something totally unrelated, like a C++ solution. :-) I approved the edit, and then tweaked it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with your change to remove the editorial comment.